# why failed ksh file for sftp unix?

Tags: ksh

I'm making a ksh file that going to send files through Sftp.
when it execute, this fail but I don't understand Why.

the client has the authorized keys for the server.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
SERSFTP="user@hots"
LOCALFILE="/home/localeFile/test.txt"
LOCALFILE="/home/remote/test.txt"
sftp $SERSFTP << !
put  $LOCALFILE $LOCALFILE
bye sftp
mv -f  $LOCALFILE $rutaold
!
exit 0
```

but when it execute:

sftp: not found

Comment: You PATH is probably wrong. But you should better ask on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you aware that you used `LOCALFILE` when you probably meant `REMOTEFILE`. Also, get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARS: one day you'll redefine $PATH and then wonder why your script is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
SERSFTP="user@hots"
LOCALFILE="/home/localeFile/test.txt"
REMOTEFILE="/home/remote/test.txt"
sftp $SERSFTP << !
put  $LOCALFILE $REMOTEFILE
bye 
!
 <ruatold is not defined here change it.>
mv -f  $LOCALFILE $rutaold

exit 0
```

Try this.